# download file from remote server and delete after complete downloading

Tags: php, linux

i try to download file from remote server by use wget. and i want to delete remote server file after complete downloading.

here is my code for download file.

```
<?php
function remoteFileExists($url) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    $ret = false;

    if ($result !== false) {
        $statusCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);  

        if ($statusCode == 200) {
            $ret = true;   
        }
    }

    curl_close($curl);

    return $ret;
}


$exists = remoteFileExists('http://192.168.X.X/123/123.rar');
if ($exists) {

    shell_exec('wget  http://192.168.X.X/123/123.rar');
    echo"file downloaded";

} else {
    echo 'file does not exist';   

}

?>
```

but this is also give error like below:

```
--2014-01-28 11:17:38--  http://192.168.X.X/123/123.rar
Connecting to 192.168.X.X:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 345 [text/plain]
123.rar: Permission denied

Cannot write to `123.rar' (Permission denied).
```

Comment: Where are you deleting it, or is that what you need help with?

Comment: @eBrian. actually i don't know what function i use for delete file after download complete.

Comment: unlink('/path/to/file') is PHP's delete function, but, you would have to have access to the server. If you don't have access to the server, you could use an API on the remote server. If you can't do either of those, deleting that file simply isn't possible.

Comment: @eBrian..  can u resolve this code why i got permission error.

Comment: The permission error is most assuredly because the folder it is being saved to does not have write access. Issue a chmod 777 on the folder to write to and that will fix that problem.

Comment: @eBrian..now no error showing ... nothing downloaded

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46193/discussion-between-codemania-and-ebrian)

Answer (score 1):

- `Cannot write to '123.rar' (Permission denied).` means that your PHP (mod_php running as Apache user?) doesn't have permissions to write the file to your local server. You would need to specify (or create, `chmod 777`) a directory where writing is permitted.

Let's assume your Apache can save to `/tmp`

```
$local_dir = '/tmp';
shell_exec("wget -P $local_dir http://192.168.X.X/123/123.rar");
```

- Deleting the remote file needs permissions and access to the remote server. Several options exist depending on your setup: `ssh remote-server "rm /path/to/123/123.rar"` if you have `ssh` access (but then you would just `scp` the file in the first place, wouldn't you?).

Comment: You did check for `/tmp/123.rar` didn't you? And you tried the `wget` command separately at the command line? And you verified that `/tmp` is writable for your PHP? (`shell_exec("touch /tmp/mytestfilename")` and verify the empty file was created)

Comment: i checked `/tmp` is writable.